# How to see what exactly is request from the request module sending?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

I am trying to login to a server using [Node.js request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). The server refuses that request.

What can I do to get **exact plaintext data** of the request the `request(options, callback)` or `request.post(options,callback)` is sending?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for debugging Request calls: https://github.com/request/request-debug. This will give you JSON output for the data being used to generate the actual requests. Note: The module is dated and doesn't seem to have evolved much.

If you are looking for a better way to monitor raw output that works in any scenario (not just Node.js), you should use a Web sniffer / debugging proxy like Wireshark or Fiddler. I've used Fiddler and I find it easy to use (and it is free and available on Mac, Windows and a beta for Linux too).

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get plaintext data? This nodule still logs request before they are converted to plaintext. The advantage of plaintext request is that i can easily compare it with request from developper tools in my browser.

Comment: @TomášZato I'm not sure I follow what you are asking then. Do you want the raw network request rather than the JSON?

Comment: Exactly, the raw HTTP data. I am not even sure why ti shows JSON instead.

Comment: Ok - modified my answer. If you are looking for a more generic way to monitor arbitrary network traffic from any apps/services written across any platform, use a network sniffer-type tool - I've recommended one that I've used before (Fiddler). Hope this helps!